# Sugar ORM как в запросе взять boolean

Tags: java, android, sugarorm

Не могу вытянуть данные с запросом на булевое значение.
Запрос делаю так:

```
List<DB> listPhrase = DB.find(Database.class, "history = ?", "true");
```

пробовал еще так:

```
List<DB> listPhrase = DB.find(DB.class, "history = ?", String.valueOf(true));
```

Данные в базу заносятся так:

```
pDB.add(new DB(1, "rrrr", tab_list_I[0], "qqqq", "wwww", "eeee", false, false, false));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
List<DB> listPhrase = DB.find(Database.class, "history = ?", "1");
```

Проблема может быть в том, что в SQLite нет типа boolean, вместо него используется [integer со значениями 0 и 1](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#boolean_datatype).

Comment: Спасибо! Это работает!